# In Corona SDK how to reverse a unicode string?

Tags: unicode, lua, coronasdk

I knew that Lua does not fully support unicode however there should be a workaround to solve this problem?
string.reverse will not work with unicode so the following example will not work

```
  print(string.reverse("أحمد"))
```

any help on that?

Comment: What flavour of unicode are you working with UTF8 or something else.  Have you reviewed the Wiki for this? http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaUnicode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Corona SDK seems to be using UTF-8 as encoding.

If you want to reverse all Unicode *code points* in a string, instead of all bytes, you can use that code:

```
function utf8reverse(str)
  return str:gsub("([\194-\244][\128-\191]+)", string.reverse):reverse()
end

print(utf8reverse("أحمد"))
```

The trick is as follows: a multibyte Unicode code point always start with a byte **11xx xxxx**, followed by one or several bytes **10xx xxxx**. The first step is to reverse all bytes on each multibyte code point, and then reverse all bytes.

Note: when a Unicode character is composed of several code points, that simple trick will not work. A full support would require a big Unicode database to deal with.

Comment: nice trick; reminds me of reversing words in a string by reversing characters in each of the words and then reversing the entire string.