# Get code point of character in Lua?

Tags: unicode, lua

I've done it before, but I'm not certain how and I have since lost the source files.

How do I get the code point of a character in Lua? Or, at least, a unique value for a character?

Comment: What's the 'unicode value'? The code point?

Comment: No, the value of a character in unicode.

Comment: I'm sorry, that's not more specific.

Comment: http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html

Comment: Ok, you want the code point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Lua 5.3, you can get the code point of a UTF-8 string with [utf8.codepoint](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-utf8.codepoint).

```
print(utf8.codepoint("瑞"))
--29790
```

Comment: Shiny new features! Thanks for posting a new answer.

Answer (score 2):

For ASCII strings it's easy:

```
local char_code = string.byte("A",1);
-- char_code now contains 65
```

For UTF-8 (assuming that's how you're representing data), it gets tricky. Either use a 3rd party library like [slnunicode](http://luaforge.net/projects/sln/), or you'll have to write your own function to pasre the UTF-8 bytes.

Your Lua install may already contain the [ValidateUnicodeString](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ValidateUnicodeString) extension, which allows this to work:

```
local char_code = string.utf8code("ٱ");
-- char_code now contains 1649
```

(That example contains an Arabic Alef Wasla, which may not display correctly in your local font)

Answer (score 1):

There are several answers that may give you what you want (if you limit yourself to UTF8):

- [Splitting a multibyte string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003747/splitting-a-multibyte-string-in-lua)
- [Iterating over UTF8 code points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235091/extract-the-first-letter-of-a-utf-8-string-with-lua/13238257#13238257)
- [Reversing a UTF8 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111508/in-corona-sdk-how-to-reverse-a-unicode-string/13112347)